# Reformatting The Content Of A File

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, fopen, explode

I have a file called "data.txt". In this file, there are 30 lines with strings who all have the same length. It looks like this:

```
2QA4ZRDUT
IDVLTLZSC
4GYC3HCMV
1W6409JD5
70P7U66TE
```

... and so on.

What I want to do now is reformatting these lines. I want 5 strings on one line, seperated with a ";". After that, I want a new line and the next 5. In the end, it should look like this:

```
2QA4ZRDUT;IDVLTLZSC;4GYC3HCMV;1W6409JD5;70P7U66TE;
NGN1TGF6G;JWVI7LSIZ;U99TMVXXK;KLBDMRPQV;MEFKLUO3;
```

... and so on, until the whole content of the file is reformatted like this.

The last hours I've been trying to accomplish this by using for, foreach and while loops but I only manage to get one line. I hope somebody can help me since I'm not that experienced with PHP.

This is the content of "data.txt":

```
2QA4ZRDUT
IDVLTLZSC
4GYC3HCMV
1W6409JD5
70P7U66TE
OG2JBBZF6
5391PHOVW
ZAJ3OZ4H2
GMOB9E9X7
Q8U4C8ZK1
0WDZLRWWJ
N487W3S24
PKXQFFEK3
NSMKC29IB
HOLI1T2ZB
DVPIVLLLS
FH7RSZWTM
9VSUWPZEX
NM6ZWV19I
NGN1TGF6G
JWVI7LSIZ
U99TMVXXK
KLBDMRPQV
MEFKLUO3L
LICFIK24W
ELGPLCK51
QQS4SOJV1
KJ2UVTU1B
FLQ6T7LG6
QJZLAPYN1
```

Comment: Hint: Use the modulus operator

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
<?php

$oldf=fopen('data.txt','r');
$newf=fopen('data_new.txt','w');
$i=0;
while(!feof($oldf))
{
    $i++;
    $line=fgets($oldf);
    fwrite($newf,$line.';');
    if($i%5==0)
       fwrite($newf,"\n");
}
fclose($oldf);
fclose($newf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $file_name = "test.txt"; // Change file name as needed
    $file_data = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $file_data_array = explode('\n', $file_data);
    $i = 0;
    $new_file_data = "";
    foreach ($file_data_array as $piece)
    {
        $new_file_data .= $piece . ';';
        $i++;
        if ($i % 5 == 0) // Change number of pieces you want on a line as needed
        {
            $new_file_data .= '\n';
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($file_name, $new_file_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$str = '2QA4ZRDUT
IDVLTLZSC
4GYC3HCMV
1W6409JD5
70P7U66TE
OG2JBBZF6
5391PHOVW
ZAJ3OZ4H2
GMOB9E9X7
Q8U4C8ZK1
0WDZLRWWJ
N487W3S24
PKXQFFEK3
NSMKC29IB
HOLI1T2ZB
DVPIVLLLS
FH7RSZWTM
9VSUWPZEX
NM6ZWV19I
NGN1TGF6G
JWVI7LSIZ
U99TMVXXK
KLBDMRPQV
MEFKLUO3L
LICFIK24W
ELGPLCK51
QQS4SOJV1
KJ2UVTU1B
FLQ6T7LG6
QJZLAPYN1';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$c = 1;
$str3 = '';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $str3.= $item.';';
    if ($c % 5 == 0) {
        $str3.= PHP_EOL;
    }
    ++$c;
}
echo "<p>$str3</p>";
```

Be aware that you won't see the line breaks in the browser, but they will be apparent when you 'view source'.

Edit: I'm using PHP_EOL here instead of "\n" as the other answers have suggested. This ensures that the script will work correctly on any platform (Win, MacOS & *nix) as long as the PHP setting [auto_detect_line_endings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) is set to true

Comment: @user1418870: Glad to have helped, now can you accept this answer please?